# When we use the XMl

Tags: xml, xml-serialization, xsd, linq-to-xml, xmlhttprequest

When we use the XMl
What user cases.

For example, can work perfectly with the XMl instead of used DataBase

What is the difference between XMl and XMLSchema.xsd and XSLTFile.xslt
asp.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd use XML when your data has a hierarchical, tree-like nature, esp. if it is recursively structured, or if it is semi-structured (formal structure and plaintext interleaved). Relational databases are capable of handling both of these cases, but they just don't fit the model as well.

Answer (score 1):

When the webpage owner doesn't have a DB.  For example a .NET provider like Brinkster charges a lot of money extra for MS SQL (although MySQL is included).  There are blog systems that use no database and use XML instead such as: http://www.dotnetblogengine.net/

You will use some features that a database offers. Personally, I save XML for sending messages and for configuration but everything with substance belongs in the database.